# How to store data for the application via REST post call

Tags: rest, grails

Hi am developing my first grails RESTful application... In that i have mapped the post request to save method.its showing some error like, Internal server Error..Can any one please help me to brief how to use the post method to save the data via REST Post request...?
My save method is as follows..

```
def save = {
    def xml = request.XML
    def post = new ImageProperties()
    post.content = xml.content.text()
    def markup
    if (post.save()) { markup = { status("OK") } }
    else { markup = { status("FAIL") } }
    render contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8", markup } }
```

and ImageProperties class as follows...

```
class ImageProperties {
    static hasMany={categories:Categories}
    String name
    String place
    String description
    String path
    String category
    Categories categories
}
```

Comment: Plese post the code you use and describe the error in more detail.

Comment: No in a comment! Please edit your post above, add your code, and indent it with four spaces :)

Comment: No `<br>` necessary for line breaks. Just post your code as it is and indent every line with four spaces.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to get familiar with the question posting interface to properly format any code samples you provide. Having properly formatted content encourages other users to help you by letting them understand your issue better.

Comment: Also, please post the stack trace and exact error message that grails is giving. (also, what version of grails is this?) And lastly, what is the request that is causing it to choke?

Comment: Am  using grails 1.3.7 and its showing error like.. No such property: content for class: imageapplication.ImageProperties... The stacktrace is too large to post

Comment: You can use this: http://pastebin.com/ to post large exception logs... or code snippets.

Comment: Ya that's ok.. am asking the save method to handle the request...Can you suggest me in the coding the save method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi after a long trial and error method i found the answer.. Hope this will be helpful for many users...

```
def save = {
    def xml = request.XML
    def post = new ImageProperties()
    post.name = xml.name.text()
    post.place = xml.place.text()
    post.path = xml.path.text()
    post.description = xml.description.text()
    post.category = xml.category.text()
    post.categories = Categories.get(xml.categories.@id.text())
    def markup

    if (post.save()) {
        markup = {
            status("OK")
        }
     } else {
            markup = {
            status("FAIL")
        }
    }
    render contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    markup
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are assigning the posted data to an expected `content` property of your `ImageProperties`

```
def post = new ImageProperties()
post.content = xml.content.text()
```

but where in your Entity is that property?

```
class ImageProperties {
    static hasMany={categories:Categories}
    String name
    String place
    String description
    String path
    String category
    Categories categories
}
```

**Update**: If you want to simply populate all properties you can use the domain class constructor:

```
def post = new ImageProperties(xml.content)
```

See more in the section [REST](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#REST) and [Data Binding](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#dataBinding) of the Grails manual.

Comment: Sorry i cant get your question.. Am trying to store the content of the posted data directly into the ImageProperties class with the help of post.content=xml.content.text()... Is that possible..? If not how can we do that..

Comment: For that you can use the domain class constructor like "new ImageProperties(xml.content)" - I've extended the anwer.